# How to give a particular role, the right to register new user

Tags: users

We have been targeted by spam bot, and decided to set the option "Who can register new user" as "Administrator only". So far so good.

I would like to let another role (Webmaster) create users as he wishes.

In the permissions settings, I checked the checkbox for "Administer users", but I feel like the option "Administrator only" in the account parameter is overwritting this.

Anyone has an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get why it's a problem, you are already there, just simply create a role "Webmaster" if you dont have one already, and give this role the same permission "Administer Users" too. but if you only want to give specific permission such as ONLY creating users you might need [Administer Users by Role](https://drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole) module

> This module allows site builders to set up fine-grained permissions
>   for allowing users to edit and delete other users — more specific than
>   Drupal Core's all-or-nothing 'administer users' permission. It also
>   provides and enforces a 'create users' permission.
>
> To use this module:
>
> Create a role for the users who you'd like to be able to
>   create/edit/delete other users Give that new role the 'administer
>   users' permission and give it the desired Administer Users by Role
>   permissions If the user-being-edited has multiple roles, the
>   user-doing-the-editing must have permission to edit ALL of the
>   user-being-edited's roles.

Comment: The webmaster has the same permission as the admin and it doesn't work. I'm gonna try the module you suggested

Comment: well if they both have the same permission and it's not working properly you might need to rebuild your permissions, in D7 go to /admin/reports/status/rebuild and hit the rebuild permissions button, clear your cache and try again, if still you have problem try checking your message logs for any errors in your drupal database, but still go ahead and try the module and let me know if it works